# Orthogonal Projector

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Let $(H,\langle\,|\,\rangle)$ be a separable Hilbert space on $\mathbb{C}$.

$P_{\psi}:=\langle\psi,\,\rangle\psi$, where $\psi\in H$ is such that $\|\psi\|=1$.

I have to prove that $P_{\psi}$ is an orthogonal projector on $H$.

I can prove $P_{\psi}P_{\psi}=P_{\psi}$, but I can't prove $P_{\psi}^*=P_{\psi}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\langle P_\psi^*\phi,\eta\rangle = \langle \phi,P_\psi\eta\rangle=\langle\,\phi,\langle\psi,\eta\rangle\,\psi\rangle\,
=\langle\psi,\eta\rangle\,\langle\phi,\psi\rangle
=\langle\,\langle\psi,\phi\rangle\,\psi,\eta\rangle=\langle P_\psi\phi,\eta\rangle.
$$
Note that we are using that the inner product is conjugate linear in the first component, and that $\langle\psi,\phi\rangle=\overline{\langle\phi,\psi\rangle}$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\xi,\eta\in H$ we have
$$\langle P_\psi(\xi),\,\eta\rangle\ =\ \big\langle \langle \psi,\xi\rangle\cdot\psi\,,\ \eta\big\rangle\ =\ \langle\psi,\xi\rangle\cdot\langle \psi,\eta\rangle$$
(assumed that conjugation happens in second variable). 
And, we get the same for $\langle \xi,\,P_\psi(\eta)\rangle\,$.